# Display a random link from my site?

Tags: php

I have a website with a lot of static content pages which are divided by categories, each category has a folder and index.html inside

[image]

What I want to do is to put some code inside the main index.php file in a way that whenever a user visits this index.php file, he will be redirected to one of my folders,

For example:

index.php code :

```
 <?php
 random_redirect_the_user();
 ?>
```

Where random_redirect_the_user() will redirect the user to http://www.example.com/wiki/(FOLDER)

And  (FOLDER) is randomly chosen and can be any folder of the ones that appear above.

**The question :**

What shall I write inside the random_redirect_the_user() to perform this kind of redirection ?

Comment: And your question? What have you tried?

Comment: will you read all paths dynamically or will you code the paths manually in your code? If you will do it automatically then you should read the folders, e.g. using scandir, and then check if path is a folder or file, and then store all folders in an array, that you later random pick from.

Comment: What did your research tell you when you tried to find something that listed the contents of a directory?

Comment: do you have list of folder names? then it ll be easy...

Comment: You don't need a list, you can find all files quickly using  `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this: First, get the array of names of all folders:

```
$dir = '/tmp'; //here set you main folder
$foldersArray = scandir($dir)
```

Then, get a random name:

```
$randomFolderKey = array_rand($foldersArray);
```

After that, do the following:

```
header('Location: www.youwebsiteUrl/'.$foldersArray[$randomFolderKey])
```

Comment: is_dir must be used to checked after scandir, scandir picks files too.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but OP wrote said that there a folders, but yes, it will be better to chek, thanks

Comment: array_rand returns indexes (array keys) not values

Answer (score 0):

```
var $directories = Read your folder list from the server (Search for: PHP Read directories)

Get a random directory (Search for: PHP random) 
// You can get a random between 0 and count($directories)

Then redirect your user: (Search for: PHP redirect | PHP header )
```

And you are done!

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you are looking for.

Hope it helps

```
function random_redirect_the_user(){
    $dir_list = array();
    $path = '/path/to/directory/';
    if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
        while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
            if($entry == '.' || $entry == '..'){
                continue;
            }
            if(is_dir ( $path.''.$entry )){
                array_push($dir_list, $path.''.$entry);
            }
        }
    }
    $count = count($dir_list);
    $random = rand(0,$count);
    return $dir_list[$random];
}

$dir = random_redirect_the_user();
echo $dir;
```